# Let $\phi: G \rightarrow H$ be a homomorphism of groups, and suppose K is a subgroup of H. Prove that $\phi^{-1}(K)$ is a subgroup of G.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have most of this proof down, I am just struggling with the inverse portion of this proof.

According to a proof in the book Algebra In Action, one of the conditions requires me to prove that for any $x\in\phi^{-1}(K)$ there must be an inverse, $x^{-1}\in\phi^{-1}(K)$.

My attempt:

Let $x\in\phi^{-1}(K)$. Then we may say $\phi(x)\in K$ by definition. Since K is a subgroup of G, then $\phi(x)^{-1}\in K$.

This is where I'm starting to get stuck. Can I finish the proof as follows:

Therefore $\phi(x)^{-1}=\phi(x^{-1}) \in K$.  Hence, we have that $x^{-1}\in\phi^{-1}(K)$

Comment: As stated below, $\phi(x)^{-1} = \phi(x^{-1})$ is always true for homomorphisms. Observe, $x x^{-1} = 1_G \Rightarrow \phi(x x^{-1}) = \phi(1_G) = 1_H = 1_K \Rightarrow \phi(x)\phi(x^{-1}) = 1_K \Rightarrow \phi(x^{-1}) = \phi(x)^{-1}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a valid end to the proof. The full justification is: there holds
$$ \phi(x)^{-1} = \phi(x^{-1}) \in K $$
since $\phi$ is a homomorphism which preserves inverses.

Answer (score 1):

The phrasing “there must be an inverse $x^{-1}\in\phi^{-1}(K)$” is not very precise. What you want to show is that *the inverse* $x^{-1}\in\phi^{-1}(K)$. The inverse $x^{-1}$ exists in $G$ and it is needed that it belongs to $\phi^{-1}(K)$.

In order to prove it, recall that the condition $g\in\phi^{-1}(K)$ is, by definition, equivalent to $\phi(g)\in K$. If $x\in\phi^{-1}(K)$, then
$$
\phi(x^{-1})=\phi(x)^{-1}\in K
$$
because $\phi(x)\in K$ and $K$ is a subgroup.

Similarly, $1\in\phi^{-1}(K)$ because $\phi(1)=1\in K$. If $x,y\in\phi^{-1}(K)$, then
$$
\phi(xy)=\phi(x)\phi(y)\in K
$$
because $K$ is a subgroup and $\phi(x),\phi(y)\in K$. Therefore $xy\in\phi^{-1}(K)$.

Comment: Great! I wish I was your student, however; I am a PhD in Algebra. I adore the way you think and seems you play with structures as you want them to be. Thanks for sharing your thoughts in Maths and Latex.